# How to send a certificate as part of request using api management

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Currently I'm reading a client certificate from the external client and then validating in apim using policies which is done using

```
    <policies>
        <inbound>
```

Now when the request is valid and must attach the servercertificate along with the request and then send it back to the client.

How must this be done? can you please help.

Comment: client is making an http call I believe. if you are using c# and HttpWebRequest. You can add a x509 certificate to the obj.ClientCertificates.add

Comment: Will you be able to give me the code snippet, Attached the error i'm facing. Actually where to attach certificate as part of request in policy.

Comment: one clarification - are you getting error in api management xml policies as shown in question or do you want to send the certificate from the client application which will consume this api ??

Answer (score 2):

Since you're putting certificate into a header you could simply bin64 encode it. You should be able to do it either by accessing RawData property or calling Export on it.